# Update AngularJS scope variables in the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following AngularJS controller function which makes a JSONP request to a webservice, gets the data as a JSON file and assigns the values to scope variables which I show in the UI by AngularJS directives such as {{variableName}}. This function works fine when I run it on page load, however it does not update the view values when I call this as a function:

```
$scope.getData = function(id) {
    $http.jsonp( webServices.getData+'?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', config ).then( function ( response ) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
        if($scope.data.status == "ok") {

        $scope.data.receivedData = campaign.receivedData;

        }
    })
}
```

Can anybody give me a hint on how can I make this update the values in the view (form input controls) dynamically when the JSONP call returns the values? I read about $apply() but not sure where and how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider it as a simple input with type text <input type="text" val="{{somevaluefromangular}}" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following solution help?

```
$http.jsonp( webServices.getData+'?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', config ).then( function ( response ) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
    if($scope.data.status == "ok") {
        $scope.data.receivedData = campaign.receivedData;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Scratch what I had earlier....

In your then promise handler you have:

```
$scope.data.receivedData = campaign.receivedData;
```

but you have not defined what campaign is, I assume that you want to set something on your $scope (what you're view will bind to) that is related to `campaign` that resides within the data coming back from the call to `webServices.getData`.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I do that: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: See the updated code, and place all of your logic inside the scope.apply, this way your only forcing the digest cycle to run once.

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same - the error http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: Have you investigated putting this call into an angular service/factory and just returning a promise from the call to the service? By doing that your controller would not have any non-angular code internally to cause conflicts w/ the digest cycle.

Comment: Thanks, Brocco. Any example code, please? I'm not sure I got what you're referring to.

Comment: I was a bit off with where I was going, please take a look at the updated answer it appears your referring to a variable you have not yet defined and I assume you're hitting a null reference error. Check your console for any errors you may be getting.

Answer (score 0):

do not bind to a function... bind to a value.
and: `return` the `promise`

```
$scope.getData = function(id) {
    // return the promise....
    return $http.jsonp( webServices.getData+'?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', config ).then( function ( response ) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
        if($scope.data.status == "ok") {

        $scope.data.receivedData = campaign.receivedData;

        }
    })
}

// fetch that data into a variable, that you bind to.
$scope.myActualData = $scope.getData();
```

if you later want to call the getData again, dont just call it, asign it again to the bound variable.

```
$scope.myActualData = $scope.getData();
```